# Doesn't ADL considers namespaces associated with template argument?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the simple code :

```
template<int N> struct foo{};

namespace N
{
    const int a=1;
    void bar(foo<1>& x){}
}

int main()
{
    bar(foo<N::a>());
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the code work? why it isn't working I wonder. Thanks

Comment: I think only the namespaces of *type* template parameters become associated for the purpose of ADL. ([Demo](https://ideone.com/1x0P9I).)

Comment: At least you need `N::bar(foo<N::a>());`, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I guess that's why the question is about ADL :-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[basic.lookup.argdep]/2:

> [ Note: Non-type template arguments do not contribute to the set of associated namespaces.—end note ]

For the code linked in the comments, a typedef in a namespace isn't sufficient either, but for other reasons. The lookup is based on the resolved type, not on the namespace containing the `typedef` itself (or, equivalently, `using`).

For example, if you had code like:

```
namespace A { 
    class T {};
}

namespace B { 
    typedef A::T TT;
}
```

Using `B::TT` as an argument would add `namespace A` to the lookup, but would not add `namespace B` to the lookup.

Comment: Thanks for answer , I modified the code but still no success http://rextester.com/AVREQ69961

Comment: @AngelusMortis Typedefs resolve too early. You just have `int`, which has no associated namespace.

Comment: @Angelus - That's still not a type from the namespace, just an alias. It would be just horrible if `foo<N::a>()` where not the same as `foo<1>()`, or `foo<N::mm>` were different from `foo<int>`.

Comment: Here's a somewhat legitimate [non-example](https://ideone.com/Uyf68R) of code that one might expect to work were one not aware of the rules.